# A .Net math expression COMPILER for Windows phone?

Tags: c#, parsing, windows-phone-8, expression, evaluator

I'm making a **function graphing** app for **windows phone** where user would input a function for the app to draw. I need a **fast** (here I mean the fastest possible) expression evaluator. I've seen a lot of math parsers out there, but it seems none of them allow for **compiling and evaluating separately**. I need this because I need to calculate a **lot of data** points (1000+) at 30 or even better 60fps. All of those I found take a string and parse it + evaluate **at the same time**. As I'm making this for windows phone, I **cannot compile c# code** directly because of restrictions.

It should be able to do something like: 2^2*sin(x/20)+abs(x)/log(x, 2)

SOLVED:

I'm really angry with myself because I couldn't google this out and finaly when I ask a question here, I find the answer myself.

This did the trick:

http://nicoschertler.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/math-parser-using-lambda-expressions/

its so good that 1.5ghz dual core phone can run it at 1/4 pixel precision at 60fps!!

Comment: How many Milliseconds? What do you mean by `fastest`? The one i made takes around 200-300 milliseconds similar to what .Net provides in the DataTable.Compute - And yes mine can call functions without recompiling. Thanks to a little bit of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Last time I checked, most of the useful meta-programming APIs did not exist on windows phone. It is hard to make a compiler without any relevant compiler APIs... so: the best you would be able to do would be sticking a tree of operators together and eval that... not exactly very efficient, though

Comment: Have you got as far as building an AST from the expression? (perhaps via a modified shunting yard algorithm, but there are lots of ways of doing it). Once you have that, translating to a runtime evaluation tree should be easy enough. Not true compiling, but as close as you'll get without the meta-programming APIs

Comment: Well, I saw what other apps on the store could do, so I'm sure it's possible just don'tknow how they did it. Acme would you share it for free?

Comment: Gravell, exactly like that. Is there something similar already done? Or am I going to have to do all by myself..

Comment: @DavidEmanuelLukšić if you used that parser and it meets your needs, you should post that as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Strange because there are quite some parser generators, which in return give you parser ready to use. It is up to you if you define evaluation while parsing, or just build a math expression for later evaluation.

One disadvantage of general parser generator is, well, the fact it is general, so it does more than you ask. On the other hand, it is easy to add something when the need strikes (I wouldn't dare touch anything in the code you linked).

My own framework (i.e. parser generator) contains very simple calculator (so it does math expression parsing) in 2 forms -- written as C# code (slow) and generated to action table (fast -- it could be faster of course).

http://sourceforge.net/projects/naivelangtools/

Comment: I find the code I linked very useful, made some changes to support multiple parameters quite easily. It isn't really commented but reasonably clean and fast. I can't really ask for anything faster.